# How to select sum of the data for every month in current year even if we do not have data

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, left-join, recursive-query

I have a SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` date NULL,
 `distance` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO test (date, distance) VALUES ('2020-01-01','1');
INSERT INTO test (date, distance) VALUES ('2020-01-15','3');
INSERT INTO test (date, distance) VALUES ('2020-02-10','1');
INSERT INTO test (date, distance) VALUES ('2020-02-20','4');
INSERT INTO test (date, distance) VALUES ('2020-05-06','8');
INSERT INTO test (date, distance) VALUES ('2020-11-12','2');
INSERT INTO test (date, distance) VALUES ('2020-11-13','5');
```

And what I want to do is to have a sum for every month from this year,
but what is important to keep months with sum of zero even if I do not have data for this month

Here is the fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9KmGk6uxBQxSRxr5Qsid3S/2

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT YEAR_MONTH(`date`) as date, SUM(distance) FROM test GROUP BY `date`;
```

Comment: _Small Hint_ Change the group by to `GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)` and you will get a better answer from the query you have

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185079/get-previous-12-month-data-and-if-not-exist-then-add-zero-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a calendar table that holds of the month of the year, than you can then `left join` with the table.

You can either create the table manually, or generate it on the fly with a recursive query (which requires MySQL 8.0):

```
with cte as (
    select date_format(current_date, '%Y-01-01') as dt
    union all select dt + interval 1 month from cte where dt < date_format(current_date, '%Y-01-01')  + interval 11 month
)
select c.dt, coalesce(sum(t.distance), 0) as sum_distance
from cte c
left join test t 
    on  t.date >= c.dt
    and t.date <  c.dt + interval 1 month
group by c.dt
order by c.dt
```